# Are there 76 different law enforcement agencies providing officers to control the DAPL protests?

Tags: law-enforcement

According to a current Facebook trending picture and [an article from the ACLU](https://www.aclu.org/blog/speak-freely/how-many-law-enforcement-agencies-does-it-take-subdue-peaceful-protest), there are 76 different law enforcement agencies involved in controlling the DAPL (Dakota Access Pipeline) protest from nine states, some of which very far away from South Dakota (Ohio, Indiana, etc.).

Is this accurate - specifically, are there actually agents from all 76 agencies at Standing Rock?